# I am trying to open a file, look for 'r' or 'R' as the first letter of every word, then print those words

Tags: python-3.x, file, pycharm

As title says... This is just an exercise I'm doing to get better at python.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

So this is what i have tried...

```
read = open('file.txt', 'r')
t = read.read()
for i[0] in t:
    if i[0] == 'r' or 'R':
        print(i[0])
```

and...

```
read = open('file.txt', 'r')
t = read.read()
for i[0] in t:
    if i[0] == 'r' or 'R':
        print(i[0])
```

also...

**EDIT....... I have been able to find the word with 'R' and 'r' but now I cant figure out how to print the word containing the 'r' and 'R'**

```
for i in t:
if i[0] == 'r' or i[0] == 'R':
        print(i)
```

i tried various types of things and this is what works. I even tried:

```
if i[0] in ['r', 'R']
```

and it didnt work for whatever reason.

any help to print the word would be appreciated cause all I get right now is

```
r R r r R
```

first one i just get an error saying i is not defined. The second just prints out every word of the document

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference between the two versions of your code (other than indentation)? Because they seem identical to me, with all the same problems.

Comment: I don't think this question is quite a duplicate, since there are several other issues going on, but [this previous question(and it's answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/1405065) are relevant to part of the problem (the `or` operator).

Comment: @Blckknght for the difference in code the indentation is just a formatting error made by me when i posted it on here. As far as everything else i had tried the in ['r', 'R'] and that doesnt work either. I figured out how  to find the words with r but now im having trouble printing the word instead of just 'r'

Answer (score 0):

You have a whole bunch of issues going on here.

The exception about `i` not being defined is from `for i[0] in t:`, where you're trying to assign a value from your iteration to the first element of some value `i` which doesn't exist. You probably want just `for i in t` without the indexing.

The next issue is what you're iterating over. When you iterate directly on a string like `t`, you get each character individually. You don't get the text split up into words, which I think is what you want. Tokenizing real text is a bit tricky, but for your purposes, you may be able to get by with `t.split()`, which splits a string on any whitespace.

Your last issues were related to using `or` incorrectly, but it looks like you may have fixed them already. Anyway, here's what I'd suggest for the final code (with some other non-essential improvements, like better variable names and a `with` statement to close the file):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

for word in text.split():
    if word[0] in 'Rr':
        print(word)
```

Comment: forgive me for I am still very new and honestly was just testing out what I have learned so far. This is much better and I honestly didnt even think to use iterations like this. So you have taught me something new which I'm grateful for, thank you for taking the time to fix this.